# Dynamically change the meta/title tag, depending on the page with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, meta

I have the structure of the document:

```
<?
    include('head.php');
    include('header.php');
    include('index_content.php');
    include('footer.php');
    include('form.php');
    include('js.php');
?>
```

When I create a new page, I use this skeleton and change only the page content. But for SEO optimization it is also necessary to change the title and meta tags. Is it possible to change this dynamically using JavaScript depending on the page. Or is it better not to bathe and write something like this:

```
<?
    include('head.php'); //beginning of the <head> tag
?>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="some description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="some keywords">
<?
    include('header.php'); - //end of </head> tag
    include('index_content.php');
    include('footer.php');
    include('form.php');
    include('js.php');
?>
```

Comment: Cant you do `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $DESCRIPTION;?>">` ?

Comment: Did you use data base for page content or static page?

Comment: I used https://prerender.io/ in my case

Comment: @SamirKarmacharya static page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly get the `php` variable into `meta` tag as shown below.

```
<?
    include('head.php'); //beginning of the <head> tag
?>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $DESCRIPTION;?>">>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $KEYWORDS;?>">>
<?
    include('header.php'); - //end of </head> tag
    include('index_content.php');
    include('footer.php');
    include('form.php');
    include('js.php');
?>
```

**UPDATE**

If you use jquery, this might work

```
$("meta[name='description']").attr("content","<?php echo $DESCRIPTION;?>");
```

Comment: Do you think bot will wait for the php variable to resolve ?

Comment: This is just a script code, when rendered in browser, it will display plain text which is easily crawled. No need for bot to go for php.

Comment: Thats perfect the page on the dom holds the value resolved but bot will crawl the variable "<?php echo $DESCRIPTION;?>" as content thats what i experinced while working

Comment: @VinodLouis, this might work. I am just setting meta content with jquery. Am i right?

Comment: this will also not work bot fires as the page loads it wont even wait for your js to load either you can achive this via server side rendering or a middleware as prerender.

Comment: use phantom.js for this purpose [link](http://phantomjs.org/). because after changing content the bot cant read it.